# Dynamic Memory allocation in 2-D Array

Tags: c++

I have to create dynamic 2d array.I was trying with the code mentioned below:

Suppose `a=512 and b =102`.So Now the 2-D Array created is `ary[512][102]`.
Now I am Creating a pointer to base location i.e `int *ptr=&(ary[0][0]);`

Now, if I am giving pointer the offset 102 i.e `ptr+=102`, it should point to &(ary[1][0]) but it doesn't point to.
If given offset of 104 then only it points to `&(ary[1][0])`. Why it requires extra 2 Offset????

Code Snippet:

```
int** ary;
ary= new int*[a];
for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
ary[i] = new int[b];
```

Comment: use a `std::vector` for the array storage

Answer (score 0):

your 2d array is dynamically allocated as your code suggested, so the address of this 2d arrays is not in sequence, thus `&(ary[0][0])+102`, you can't grantee the pointer returned is the next row. So in this case, you should just use `&(ary[1][0])`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your 2-D array is not necessarily linear in the actual memory. So you can not write a program assumming that the memory is linear. 
The reason for 104 pointing to ary[1][0] could be the boundary alignment. The run time system chooses to use 104 bytes for your ary[i], rather than 102.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in the static allocation of 2D arrays, the addresses are not consecutive for the whole array when you use multiple `new`. Instead when you call for `new()` to create rows of a 2D array each new returns completely unrelated addresses which are allocated from heap. So you have to use `ary[n]` to access elements of `(n + 1)th` row and `ary[n+1]` to access elements of `(n+2)th` row and so on.